# How to create Tomcat project on myeclipse 8.5

Tags: tomcat, myeclipse

I inherited a project which is already in the web application form. This project is imported as a java project and then defining it as a tomcat project. This was easy with MyEclipse 6 but i have some problem with MyEclipse 8.6.

In MyEclipse 6.0 there is a option on configuring a project as tomcat project. This is done by checking

`<right click on project>->property->tomcat-><checking 'this is a tomcat project'>`.

I can't find the same option in MyEclipse 8.6.1. Can any body help me with this.

Is there any turn around.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific setting to make project specific to a particular server (though that is blurred a bit by MyEclipse Blue Edition, for WebSphere projects). Just deploy to Tomcat. If you have problem with deployment, it is best to ask for support on [the MyEclipse website](http://www.myeclipseide.com/forums).

Release 8.6.1 is a bit old now. You can upgrade to the latest release 10.7.1 (with release 11 imminent) for no extra charge.

Comment: thanks. but for time being is there a way to define is as tomcat project as it was possible with myeclipse 6.0.

Comment: I don't see the project property that you say existed in ME 6 (I tried with 6.6). Maybe the ME6 installation had other plugins installed? If WTP Extras was enabled in eclipse capabilities, you get to create a Dynamic Web project and attach a server runtime to it (and a Tomcat runtime can be defined) but that isn't necessary with MyEclipse Web projects. I'm not sure what you think defining the project as a Tomcat project will provide but perhaps a better place for this support is the MyEclipse forums.